# How to combine multiple arrays php like this

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have multiple arrays like the below arrays

```
    $in = array(array("","","111","1552"),array("102","","","1552"),array("102","123","","1552"),array("","123","","") );
```

Need output like this
"101","","111","1552"

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your best attempt.

Comment: 1) $array3 = $array1+$array2;
2) $array3 = (array_unique(array_merge($array1,$array2)));
3) $array3 = array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2);
4)  $array3 = array_merge($array2, array_filter($array1));

Comment: tried these 4 ways

Comment: Move your code to the question from comments

Comment: What are you even asking? You have to explain it in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use array_map to create array with not empty items

```
$arr = array_map(function($a, $b) { return !empty($a) ? $a : $b; }, $array1, $array2 );
```

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ad4d33eb37136c2e2e514ec0d70943a9a43bbeb1)

Comment: this will work. i have another small request. actually we have multiple array values like this

Comment: $array1 = array("","","111","1552");
$array2 = array("102","","","1552");
$array3 = array("102","123","","1552");
$array4 = array("","123","","");

Comment: Need to get "101","","111","1552"  this output

Comment: If more then one non-empty values are present for the same index, what do yuo want to get - the first or the last?

Answer (score 0):

On of the possible and very easy way

```
$array1 = array("101","","","1552");
$array2 = array("","","111","");

$result = [];
foreach ($array1 as $key => $item) {
    $result[] = $item ? $item : $array2[$key];
}

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: if we have multiple arrays. how can we do this?. please help me